# Literal numbers in FloatingPoint protocol

Tags: swift, generics

Having not much to do over the holidays, I finally got round to updating my maths library to use the `FloatingPoint` protocol, and get rid of all the duplicate code. To my surprise, I got bitten pretty much straight away by literal numbers:

```
func uprightAngle1<T: FloatingPoint>(_ x: T) -> T {
    if (x > 0.5 * T.pi) && (x < 1.5 * T.pi) { // *** ERROR HERE
        // binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'T'
        return x - T.pi
    } else {
        return x
    }
}
```

however, *this* works fine:

```
func uprightAngle2<T: FloatingPoint>(_ x: T) -> T {
    if (x > T.pi / 2) && (x < 3 * T.pi / 2) { // All fine here
        return x - T.pi
    } else {
        return x
    }
}
```

Can anyone

A) explain why the compiler is inferring the type correctly with the integer literals, but not with the floating point literal,

B) show me the idiom to use when I can't use rationals as neither `let half: T = 0.5` nor `T(0.5)` compile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FloatingPoint` protocol inherits from `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`
via the inheritance chain

```
FloatingPoint - SignedNumeric - Numeric - ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral
```

and that is why the second function `uprightAngle2` compiles: Values
of the type `T` are created from the integer literals `2` and `3`.

The first function `uprightAngle1` does not compile because
the `FloatingPoint` protocol does *not* inherit from `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`, i.e. values of type `T` can not
be created from a floating point literal like `1.5`.

Possible solutions:

- Create rational values as `let half: T = 1/2`. (*Not* `let half = T(1/2)`,
  that would truncate the division result before creating the `T`
  value.)
- Replace `FloatingPoint` by `BinaryFloatingPoint` (which inherits
  from `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`).

For more information about the design of the floating point
protocols see [SE-0067 Enhanced Floating Point Protocols](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0067-floating-point-protocols.md).

The floating point types in the Swift Standard Library (`Double`, `Float`, `CGFloat`, `Float80`) as well as
`CGFloat` from the Core Graphics framework all conform to the
`BinaryFloatingPoint` protocol, so this protocol is "sufficiently
generic" for many applications.

Comment: Thanks - the pointer to `BinaryFloatingPoint` is what I was looking for. That, indeed, is the answer as it both supports literal numbers and initialisation `T(...)`. What, then, is the point of exposing `FloatingPoint`?

Comment: See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0067-floating-point-protocols.md for the design of the floating point protocols.

Comment: Thank you! I guess you might update your answer to be more emphatic about using `BinaryFloatingPoint` and avoiding `FloatingPoint`?

Comment: @MartinR Off topic: I noticed your husky is the Trello mascot. Do you work for them? :o

Comment: @Alexander: No, that is a "hat" from winter bash 2015 :)

Comment: @MartinR Nono, not the hat, [the husky](https://www.google.ca/search?q=trello+husky&client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV4_ncirPYAhXhTN8KHSveAkMQ_AUICigB&biw=1584&bih=1223)

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, that was the "Researcher" hat in 2015: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270788/is-there-a-list-of-what-each-of-the-winter-bash-hats-is-named-after/270799.

Comment: @MartinR Nvm. :p

Comment: @Alexander: But I wasn't aware that it is the Trello mascot, I just liked the picture ...

Comment: @MartinR It's a cute husky ^_^, I just noticed it today