# How to use FloatingPoint generic type for Float/Double

Tags: swift

I'd like to make the function below work both with Float and Double values:

```
func srgb2linear(_ S: Float) -> Float {
  if S <= 0.04045 {
    return S / 12.92
  } else {
    return pow((S + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
  }
}
```

The [Swift 4 Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint) says that what I need is a `FloatingPoint` generic, to represent both Float and Double classes, like:

```
func srgb2linear<T: FloatingPoint>(_ S: T) -> T
```

However when I try to do this, it doesn't compile with the following errors:

```
Error: binary operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'Double'
Error: binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'Double'
Error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'Double'
```

How is it possible that for a generic representing floating point numbers such operators are not implemented? And if not like this, how can I write this function in Swift?

Comment: One problem is that `12.92` etc are not recognized as FloatingPoint literals, that can be solved by using BinaryFloatingPoint instead (compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/48021458/1187415). – The other problem is that there is no generic `pow` function.

Comment: I've read your other answer and also SE-0067, but I don't understand why the need to use `BinaryFloatingPoint` here. It says that FP conforms to `Comparable` and that BFP "adds some additional operations that only make sense for a fixed radix".

Comment: The problem are not the comparison but the literal constants `0.04045` etc, and the pow function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that `FloatingPoint` is not a subprotocol of `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`, so your floating-point literals cannot necessarily be converted to `T`. You can solve this either by changing `FloatingPoint` to `BinaryFloatingPoint` (which is a subprotocol of `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`) or by adding `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral` as a separate requirement.

Then you will run into the problem that there is no `pow` function that is generic over `FloatingPoint`, and no member of `FloatingPoint` or `BinaryFloatingPoint` that performs exponentiation. You can solve this by creating a new protocol and conforming the existing floating-point types to it:

```
protocol Exponentiatable {
    func toPower(_ power: Self) -> Self
}

extension Float: Exponentiatable {
    func toPower(_ power: Float) -> Float { return pow(self, power) }
}

extension Double: Exponentiatable {
    func toPower(_ power: Double) -> Double { return pow(self, power) }
}

extension CGFloat: Exponentiatable {
    func toPower(_ power: CGFloat) -> CGFloat { return pow(self, power) }
}
```

Note that there is also a `Float80` type, but the standard library doesn't provide a `pow` function for it.

Now we can write a working generic function:

```
func srgb2linear<T: FloatingPoint>(_ S: T) -> T
    where T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral, T: Exponentiatable
{
    if S <= 0.04045 {
        return S / 12.92
    } else {
        return ((S + 0.055) / 1.055).toPower(2.4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a second one with Double arguments:

```
func srgb2linear(_ S: Double) -> Double {
  if S <= 0.04045 {
    return S / 12.92
  } else {
    return pow((S + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
  }
}
```

or, if Float<->Double conversions are not a concern :

```
func srgb2linear(_ S: Double) -> Double {
  return Double(srgb2linear(Float(S)))
}
```