# Converting a function to deal with Double and Float... using FloatingPoint type?

Tags: swift, floating-point, double

I have seen a similar question on SO but it does not answer everything I am asking here.

I have a function like this:

```
  func myFunctionDouble (_ valores:[Double] = []) -> Array<Double> {

    let numeroItens = valores.count
    var c = [Double](repeating: 0,
                     count: numeroItens)

    let factor : Double = Double.pi / Double(numeroItens)

    for i in 0..<numeroItens {
      var sum : Double = 0
      for j in 0..<numeroItens {
        sum = sum + valores[j] * cos ((Double(j) + 0.5) * Double(i) * factor)
      }
      c[i] = sum
    }
    return c;
  }
```

I want to transform this function to deal with Double and Float.

I thought about replacing `Double` with `FloatingPoint` but it will simply not work and give me a bunch of errors.

There is no `FloatingPoint.pi` or array `c` cannot be declared  like

```
var c = [FloatingPoint](repeating: 0, count: numeroItens)
```

is there a way to do that?

and more than that, how do I declare a var or an array to be of `FloatingPoint` type, I mean, to accept both `Float` and `Double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example set forth in [Rob's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff) answer to [How to use FloatingPoint generic type for Float/Double](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48770538/1226963), you can do the following:

```
import Darwin // minimal necessary import
// importing Foundation, AppKit or UIKit also implicitly import Darwin

protocol Cosineable {
    func cosine() -> Self
}

extension Float: Cosineable {
    func cosine() -> Float { return cos(self) }
}

extension Double: Cosineable {
    func cosine() -> Double { return cos(self) }
}

func myFunction<T: FloatingPoint>(_ valores:[T] = []) -> Array<T> where T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral, T: Cosineable {

    let numeroItens = valores.count
    var c = [T](repeating: 0,
                     count: numeroItens)

    let factor : T = T.pi / T(numeroItens)

    for i in 0..<numeroItens {
        var sum : T = 0
        for j in 0..<numeroItens {
            sum += valores[j] * ((T(j) + 0.5) * T(i) * factor).cosine()
        }
        c[i] = sum
    }
    return c
}
```

Comment: wow this is ancient Klingon to me. Care to explain how it works? Thanks.

Comment: 80% of this is plain old generics. Read the Generics chapter in the Swift book if needed. The last 20% (obtained from the linked answer) was the trick to support calling the `cos` function with the generic.

Answer (score 2):

Added on to @rmaddy's solution, you can drastically simplify your code by using higher order functions to remove all the "noise", things which are necessary for the computation, but aren't actually that specific to your computation.

```
func myFunction<T: FloatingPoint>(_ valores:[T] = []) -> Array<T>
    where T: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral, T: Cosineable {
    let factor: T = T.pi / T(valores.count)

    return valores.indices.map { i in
        return valores.enumerated()
            .map { (offset, element) in
                element * ((T(offset) + 0.5) * T(i) * factor).cosine()
            }
            .reduce(0, +)
    }
}
```

From here, you can start labelling the terms better, and providing more context as to what these do.

The term `element * ((T(offset) + 0.5) * T(i) * factor).cosine()` is faaaaarrrrr too complicated for a single expression. Why `0.5`? What's `factor`? Why are we taking the `cosine`? It's very non-obvious. Not only will strangers to this code not understand this, but over time, you yourself will forget about this and become a "stranger" to the code.